# Remove appended network name from MYSQL user host

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

When using 'skip-name-resolve' in MYSQL I can only access MYSQL if the docker network name is appended to the user (container) otherwise I get an error such as.

```
Access denied for user 'user'@'container.dockernetwork_default'
```

Is there a way to remove the need for the appended network name and only use the container name without switching to IP hosts?

Comment: Should be possible with the host wildchar `%`  "host_name string containing special characters or wildcard characters (such as . or %); for example, 'test-user'@'%.com'. " source  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html

Comment: Looks like that'll be it. Thanks Raymond